# how to update the count of the "retry column" when the spring retries invoke web services

Tags: database, spring-retry

Am trying to use spring-retry and i want to update my DB every time the spring-retry works for 5 retries.

In database a column need to be updated in order to track if the retry was made 5 times or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `RetryListener` to the `RetryTemplate`; the count is in the `RetryContext` argument passed in.

You can add more information to the context if needed, by getting a reference to it using the `RetrySynchronizationManager`.